# Is is safe to remove the stock email and calendar app on Cyanogenmod or AOSP?

Tags: cyanogenmod, calendar, stock-email-app, vanilla-android, system-apps

Is it safe for me to remove the stock email and calendar applications on from Cyanogenmod ROM? I'm using Gmail and Google Calendar so I don't have need for the stock ones. I could simply disable them but if I removed them entirely, I might be able to save a bit on space on my system partition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YES, you can delete the stock Email (Email.apk) and stock Calendar (Calendar.apk, CalendarProvider.apk) app. For a list of other apps you can delete on CyanogenMod, see the [expandable list](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Barebones) at the bottom of the CM wiki.

I'm not so sure for AOSP though.

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted email, calendar, a bunch of other Lenovo (vendor specific), and Google apps with System app deleter and the phone works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the standard CyanogenMod mail app and everything seems to work fine